# Ruby Regex or Parser

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have a string I want to parse that looks a bit like github markdown, but I really don't want the full implementation. The string will be a mixture of "code" blocks and "text" blocks. The code blocks will be three backticks followed by an optional "language" then some code and finally three more backticks. Non-code will be pretty much everything else. I don't (but possibly should) care if the user can't input three backticks in the "text" blocks. Here's an example ...

````
This is some text followed by a code block
```ruby
def function
   "hello"
end
```
Some more text
````

Of course there may be more code and text blocks interspersed. I've tried writing a regex for this and it seemed to work but I couldn't get the groups (in parens) to give me all of the matches and scan() loses the ordering. I've looked at using a couple of ruby parsers (treetop, parselet), but the look a bit big for what I want, but I am willing to go that route if that's my best option.

Thoughts?

A couple of people have asked for the RE I was trying (many variations of below) ...

````
re = 
  /
    ```\s*\w+\s*          # 3 backticks followed by the language
      (?!```).*?          # The code everything that's not 3 backticks
    ```                   # 3 more backticks
    |                     # OR
    (?!```).*             # Some text that doesn't include 3 backticks
  /x                      # Ignore white space in RE
````

It seems though that even in simple cases for example

```
md = /(a|b)*/.match("abaaabaa")
```

I'm not able to get all of the a's and b's. from say md[3] which doesn't exist. Hope that makes more sense and that's why I don't think a RE will work in my case, but I wouldn't mind being proven wrong.

Comment: Without knowing what you're using for a regex it's difficult to help. If you're *certain* there are no other places three backticks will occur (risky, IMO, but doable) I'm not sure what the issue is. At worst you could line-by-line it.

Comment: What result do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but I would suggest going line-by-line and using Regex to match the lines. Matching the code blocks for example would then be simply matching three backticks with no previous characters on the line, followed by a valid language token. You would then scan-by-line until you match a line with only three backticks. You can avoid backticks in text by using the rules above (no chars before or after the back ticks except a valid language. That's at least where I'd start.

Comment: a regular expression engine (at least a traditional nfa-like one, like the one in ruby) only searches until it matches. also there is no multiple capture in regex, a capture (from group parentheses) will only get you the last match it captured. Also trying to get all of this by using one regex-match call should be really slow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be making some assumptions here, based on my knowledge about Markdown(github-, stackoverflow-flavors) and your question (which isn't very precise as to the rest of the text).

1.
    Every code block **starts** with a singular line,
    that only includes three backticks, an optional 
    language-name and the newline-char.

2.
    Every code block **ends** with a singular line only
    containing three backticks.

3.
    A code block is not empty.

If you can accept these assumptions, the following code should work
(assuming the text is in the `str` variable):

````
regex = %r{
  ^```[[:blank:]]*(?<lang>\w+)?[[:blank:]]*\n # matches start of codeblock, and captures optional :lang.
    (?<content>.+?) # matches codeblock content and captures in :content
  \n[[:blank:]]*```[[:blank:]]*\n # matches ending of codeblock.
}xm # free-space mode and . matches newline.
position = 0
matches = []
while(match = regex.match(str,position)) do
  position = match.end 0
  matches << [match[:lang], match[:content]]
end
````

After this matches contains an array of arrays, in which an inner array represents a match
with the first element being the (optional) language, which may be nil, and the second element
being the content.

If you have more assumptions on the text, i could alter the regular expression.

This is the teststring i used:

````
str = %{
this is some random text.
```ruby
  def print
    puts "this is a code block with lang-argument"
  end
```

some other text follows here.
i want some ``` backticks here.

```
  def print
    puts "this is a code block without lang-argument"
  end
```
}
````

Comment: This looks pretty reasonable, but I can't seem to get it to work (the regex that is). What is the string you're using to test with? Here's one I've been testing with ...
<pre>
code = "```ruby\\ndef\\nabc\\nend\\n```\\nThis is some text.\\nMore text.```ruby\\ndef\\ndef\\nend\\n```\nStill more text."
</pre>
I think I can probably get your mechanism and regex to work if I can see what you're testing with.

P.S. Can not get it formatted correctly. Hopefully, you can see what I'm getting at.

Comment: I'm not acutally seeing any matches when we're through with the loop. In fact, it doesn't seem like it's entering the loop so I don't think there's any matches. I tried grabbing directly from the edit block so I made sure I had the right code. I'm running ruby 1.9.3 are you possibly running a different version that might make a difference?

Comment: I got it. The str variable when I pasted had spaces in front of the backticks. Thanks for the help. Marking solved.